# Semantic input error message inside label

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, semantic-markup, wai-aria

I'm using `<label>` to wrap an input such that its success and error messages can appear inside its label for association. What do you think is the most semantic markup for this scenario?

```
<label>
  <b>Username</b>
  <input>
  <strong>Username already taken :(</strong>
</label>
```

For errors is `strong` appropriate? Or is `span` better? Is `role=status` appropriate?

Comment: (not an answer) You can use a span for the text of your label (it's already in a label) and strong/span/em/i/b won't change anything for current screen readers: it'll be read (though one of those elements may have a better semantics than others, SR have to cope with current state of HTML markup out there which is far from being semantics ^^)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The WCAG provides an example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/ARIA21#ARIA21-description) of error displaying using  both `aria-invalid` and `aria-describedby` properties.

In your example, the code would be:

```
<label>
  <b>Username</b>
  <input aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error">
  <strong id="error">Username already taken :(</strong>
</label>
```

The `strong` is appropriate as it appears to be an important notice. An `alert` role (rather than `status`) would be more appropriate to be applied to the `#error` element [according to the W3C](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_role_of_alert_for_Error_Feedback_in_Forms).

Comment: Thanks =) Does using `[aria-describedby]` inside `<label>` destroy the normal label semantics? Based on reading I wonder if `[aria-invalid]` would suffice in combination with the `strong` being inside `label`.

Comment: @ryanve `aria-describedby` does not affect the normal label semantics in which it differs from using `aria-labelledby`. But its true that the fact that `strong` in inside the `label` may have the effect of adding its content to the label text. Putting the `strong` tag outside the `label` tag may be pertinent when using `aria-describedby` as it will differenciate the label (`label` or `aria-labelledby`) and the description (`aria-describedby`).

Comment: After digging deeper I found there is a more specific `aria-errormessage` attribute too https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-errormessage

Comment: @ryanve with no support by assistive technologies

Comment: Thanks! Beyond https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/ Is there anywhere to get compatibility coverage for ARIA in a format similar to http://node.green or caniuse? There's only https://caniuse.com/#search=aria there

Answer (score 2):

Using a strong tag is appropriate.

Strong tags signify something is of bigger importance, and the password being incorrect is important, as it blocks the user from proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

Technically both elements can be used to create the appropriate looking error message that you are looking for (with the proper css). The most semantic, in my opinion would be to use the Strong tag, purely because I would want to stress the importance of a password being incorrect, without needing to use the `font-weight:bold;`in css.

Also since the question of accessibility is involved, the Strong tag is better for screen readers and in turn makes it more accessible.

Overall, I think its quicker, easier and better to use `<strong>`over `<span>` in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Strong is good because "Username is already taken" is a serious notice rather than a casual one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to keep it strong tag
and also make use of CSS red color to display it as an error.